# Bouncy Castle C# - PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey 'Unknown object in GetInstance'

Tags: c#, bouncycastle

I have a sample C# script that handle decryption. By using the key provided with the sample, the code is working fine:

```
public static string DecryptByPrivateKey(string s, string key)
        {
            s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");
            IAsymmetricBlockCipher engine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            engine.Init(false, GetPrivateKeyParameter(key));
            byte[] byteData = Convert.FromBase64String(s);
            var resultData = engine.ProcessBlock(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
            return CommonHelper.EncodeBase64(resultData);
        }

private static AsymmetricKeyParameter GetPrivateKeyParameter(string s)
        {
            s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");
            byte[] privateInfoByte = Convert.FromBase64String(s);            
            AsymmetricKeyParameter priKey = PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateInfoByte);
            return priKey;
        }
```

However, when using our own private key, above function will throw exception at `PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey()`:

> System.ArgumentException:  'Unknown object in GetInstance:
> Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.DerInteger Parameter name: obj'

Our public/private key strings are generated with openssl on windows with command line:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -nodes -out cert.key
openssl rsa -in cert.key -out cert_private.key
openssl rsa -in cert.key -pubout -out cert_public.key
```

The key strings are in base64 format. The sample private key have 1624 characters while our private key has 1592 only.

In Visual Studio debug mode I checked the parameter privateInfoByte is a "byte[1192]". I have no clue on the error.

I am not sure my key strings are in correct format. How can I verify? Thank you.

Comment: Private RSA keys can have different formats (e.g. PKCS#8, PKCS#1). What format do the involved keys have? Or post example keys and the _exact_ OpenSSL statement.

Comment: @Topaco I have added the openssl command line. Thanks

Comment: As said before, the format is probably not correct. According to the documentation [`PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey()`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PrivateKeyFactory.html#createKey-byte:A-) expects a private key in PKCS#8 format. However, `cert_private.key` has PKCS#1 format (`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`). `cert.key` should actually contain (among other things) the private key _already_ in PKCS#8 format (`-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`). Otherwise the private PKCS#1 key can be converted: `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in ... -out ...`

Comment: @Topaco sorry for late respond. Do you mean I should export my privatekey/publickey using different command? e.g. `openssl pkcs8 ` or  `openssl pkcs8  pkcs7`

Comment: Get the PKCS#8 key from the cert.key or convert the PKCS#1 key to PKCS#8.

Comment: @Topaco I got the pkcs8 key from cert.key as you said. Now my program is working as expected. Do you want to make it as answer to my question? Thank you!

Comment: You' re welcome. I put my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, [`PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey()`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/util/PrivateKeyFactory.html#createKey-byte:A-) expects a private key in PKCS#8 format. However, *cert_private.key* has the PKCS#1 format, which is thus incompatible.

*cert.key*, on the other hand, contains among other things the private key in PKCS#8 format, which can be extracted from this. Alternatively, the PKCS#1 formatted key can be converted to a PKCS#8 formatted key using OpenSSL, see [*openssl pkcs8*](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man1/pkcs8.html):

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in <pkcs#1 key file> -out <pkcs#8 key file>
```

---

*cert_private.key* and *cert.key* contain the PEM encoded keys consisting of header, footer and the Base64 encoding of the DER encoded keys.
`PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey()` expects a DER encoded key, i.e. from the PEM encoded key determined e.g. from *cert.key*, header, footer and line breaks are to be removed and the rest has to be Base64 decoded (which seems to be already considered in your code).
Header/footer of the PEM encoded PKCS#8 key are `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----`/`-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` and of the PEM encoded PKCS#1 key `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` / `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`.

---

**Edit:**

The statement [`openssl pkcs12 -out... -in...`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/pkcs12.html) parses a PKCS#12 file and writes the contained certificates and private keys PEM encoded to a file. `-nocerts` causes the contained certificates not to be written, `-nodes` causes the private keys not to be encrypted (i.e. your statement exports only the PEM encoded private key unencrypted). The format of the exported private key is not explicitly specified, but can be easily identified as PKCS#8 using header/footer or an ASN.1 parser.

The statement [`openssl rsa -in... -out...`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-rsa.html) finally exports the PKCS#8 formatted key to a PKCS#1 formatted key (PEM encoded). So to get the needed PKCS#8 formatted key you have the option to 1st use the PKCS#8 formatted key exported directly from the PKCS#12 file (s. previous section) or 2nd convert the PKCS#1 formatted key back to a PKCS#8 formatted key.

Therefore: yes, *cert.pfx* is a file in PKCS#12 format, and yes, *cert_private.key* is a key in PKCS#1 format, which is *incompatible* with `PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey()`, which requires a key in PKCS#8 format.

Comment: I thought I was using PKCS#12 format (because the first command line consist `pkcs12` ) but actually I was using PKCS#1?

Comment: @Mark - Please see the edit section of my answer.

Comment: If it can be of interest to someone, I wrote a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78155972/213871) that read a private key in both PEM/DER encodings, and also both PKCS1/PKCS8 formats.